# Expand Array property in Object to Multiple Objects populated w/ Array value

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

This question title is terrible but it's hard to put in words, the following example will hopefully clear things up.

I'm still learning the more advanced functions of Ramda and spent most of my day trying to get this transformation more succinct in Ramda but the ES6 version still feels more readable and short.

I was hoping a Ramda whiz could help to express this function in a better way, using less functions, maybe shorter.

Is there a better way to write this in Ramda or plain JS?
Thank you!

**Update:** added some extra properties to the objects as the intention is to keep those intact in the new array of objects.

[Link to Ramda REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?%2F%2F%20For%20every%20type%20in%20bundle.types%20creates%20a%20new%20bundle%20obj.%0A%0Aconst%20bundles%20%3D%20%5B%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09name%3A%20%27banana%27%2C%0A%09%09types%3A%20%5B%27esm%27%2C%20%27umd%27%5D%0A%09%7D%2C%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09name%3A%20%27apple%27%2C%0A%09%09types%3A%20%5B%27umd%27%5D%0A%09%7D%0A%5D%0A%0A%2F%2A%20%3D%3E%0A%5B%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09name%3A%20%27banana%27%2C%0A%09%09type%3A%20%27esm%27%0A%09%7D%2C%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09name%3A%20%27banana%27%2C%0A%09%09type%3A%20%27umd%27%0A%09%7D%2C%0A%09%7B%0A%09%09name%3A%20%27apple%27%2C%0A%09%09type%3A%20%27umd%27%0A%09%7D%0A%5D%0A%2A%2F%0A%0Alet%20allBundles%20%3D%20R.chain%28R.converge%28%0A%09R.pipe%28R.xprod%2C%20R.map%28R.mergeAll%29%29%2C%0A%09%5B%0A%09%09R.pipe%28R.dissoc%28%27types%27%29%2C%20R.of%29%2C%0A%09%09R.pipe%28R.prop%28%27types%27%29%2C%20R.map%28R.objOf%28%27type%27%29%29%29%0A%09%5D%0A%29%2C%20bundles%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%27ramda%27%29%3B%0Aconsole.log%28JSON.stringify%28allBundles%2C%20null%2C%202%29%29%3B%0A%0AallBundles%20%3D%20bundles.reduce%28%28acc%2C%20b%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09return%20acc.concat%28b.types.map%28%28type%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%09%09const%20bundle%20%3D%20%7B%20...b%2C%20type%20%7D%3B%0A%09%09delete%20bundle.types%3B%0A%09%09return%20bundle%3B%0A%09%7D%29%29%3B%0A%7D%2C%20%5B%5D%29%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log%28%27lamda%27%29%0Aconsole.log%28JSON.stringify%28allBundles%2C%20null%2C%202%29%29%3B%0A)

```js
// For every type in bundle.types creates a new bundle obj.

const bundles = [
  {
    name: 'banana',
    input: 'src/banana.js',
    dir: 'dist',
    types: ['esm', 'umd']
  },
  {
    name: 'apple',
    input: 'src/apple.js',
    dir: 'dist',
    types: ['umd']
  }
]

/* =>
[
  {
    name: 'banana',
    input: 'src/banana.js',
    dir: 'dist',
    type: 'esm'
  },
  {
    name: 'banana',
    input: 'src/banana.js',
    dir: 'dist',
    type: 'umd'
  },
  {
    name: 'apple',
    input: 'src/apple.js',
    dir: 'dist',
    type: 'umd'
  }
]
*/

let allBundles = R.chain(R.converge(
  R.pipe(R.xprod, R.map(R.mergeAll)),
  [
    R.pipe(R.dissoc('types'), R.of),
    R.pipe(R.prop('types'), R.map(R.objOf('type')))
  ]
), bundles);

console.log('ramda');
console.log(JSON.stringify(allBundles, null, 2));

allBundles = bundles.reduce((acc, b) => {
  return acc.concat(b.types.map((type) => {
    const bundle = { ...b, type };
    delete bundle.types;
    return bundle;
  }));
}, []);

console.log('lamda')
console.log(JSON.stringify(allBundles, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@0.25.0/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the perfect place to use [`R.chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain):

```js
const bundles = [ { name:  "banana"
                  , input: "src/banana.js"
                  , dir:   "dist"
                  , types: ["esm", "umd"]
                  }
                , { name:  "apple"
                  , input: "src/apple.js"
                  , dir:   "dist"
                  , types: ["umd"]
                  }
                ];

const unbundle = ({ types, ...rest }) =>
    types.map(type => ({ ...rest, type }));

const unbundleAll = R.chain(unbundle);

console.log(JSON.stringify(unbundleAll(bundles), null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@0.25.0/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the same thing in vanilla JS:

```js
const bundles = [ { name:  "banana"
                  , input: "src/banana.js"
                  , dir:   "dist"
                  , types: ["esm", "umd"]
                  }
                , { name:  "apple"
                  , input: "src/apple.js"
                  , dir:   "dist"
                  , types: ["umd"]
                  }
                ];

const unbundle = ({ types, ...rest }) =>
    types.map(type => ({ ...rest, type }));

const concatMap = f => xs => [].concat(...xs.map(f));

const unbundleAll = concatMap(unbundle);

console.log(JSON.stringify(unbundleAll(bundles), null, 2));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome! Only concern is that all the prop names are listed, it would be great if it would automatically include properties that were added later without refactoring the function...

Comment: @luwes Edited. Now you don't need to list all the property names.

Comment: Wow great use of the object spread to exclude, didn't think of that.
Thanks, accepted!

Answer (score 1):

```
const bundles = [
    { name: 'banana', types: ['esm', 'umd'] },
    { name: 'apple', types: ['umd'] }
];

let newArray = [];
bundles.forEach(bundle => {
    bundle.types.map(type => {
      newArray.push({ name: bundle.name, type })
    });
});
console.log(newArray);

This will output =>
[
  {
   "name": "banana",
   "type": "esm"
  },
  {
    "name": "banana",
    "type": "umd"
  },
  {
    "name": "apple",
    "type": "umd"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not good in Ramda, but in JS I see potential:

```js
const allBundles = bundles.reduce(
    (acc, { types, ...attrs}) => 
        [...acc, ...types.map((type) => ({...attrs, type }))], []);

const bundles = [
    { name: 'banana', types: ['esm', 'umd'] }, 
    { name: 'apple', types: ['umd'] },
];

console.log('lamda')
console.log(JSON.stringify(allBundles, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@0.25.0/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

This would have looked slightly better with `flaMap`.

Comment: Thanks @Sylwester, your answer looks good only the goal is to keep all props intact from the object, it could have any number of props. It wasn't so clear first, I added some more props to the objects.

Comment: @luwes like this?

Answer (score 0):

In JS I would go for:

```
const bundles = [
    {
        name: 'banana',
        types: ['esm', 'umd']
    },
    {
       name: 'apple',
       types: ['umd']
    }
];

const expanded = (arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((o,n)=>{
     let result = n.types.map((t)=>{
      return {name:n.name, type:t}
     });
     o = [...o,...result];
     return o;
    }, []);
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rv9Los0c/5/).

Explanation: 
What you want is an array, of objects (therefore `reduce` to collect the result), which are build by a collection built from a `map` over the types.

**I have no knowledge of RamdaJS**

From looking at the documentation, a transformation with Ramda using [R.Reduce](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduce) and [R.map](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map) should be straigthforward.

In order to get the types, you could leverage [pluck](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pluck).